# Discord Bot send a message when the user says a word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content == 'ping') {
        message.reply('Pong');
    }
});

bot.login('my token is here');
```

I want my bot to say something when the user says something that contains 'server IP' 
I currently have this code, but it only replies when I send 'ping', how can I make it where it detects when the word 'ping' is in the sentence?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.includes(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the [`content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) (returns a string) of a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) contains 'ping'.

Like so:

```
if(message.content.includes('ping')) {
    message.reply('Pong');
}
```